# os.utime() doesn't change st_atime in a loop

Tags: python, windows-10, ntfs, stat, python-os

I'm using a function to change the st_atime & st_mtime for files in a directory and the function looks like below (fileStatusDFOld is a df containing all the files' full directory):

```
for index, row in fileStatusDFOld.iterrows():
    fileDirectory = row['fileDirectory']
    st_atime_new = 1652809720.254151
    st_mtime_new = 1652409008.6503568

    os.utime(fileDirectory,
             (st_atime_new, st_mtime_new)
             )
```

After running the function, st_mtime will be changed to the desired value but the st_atime will always be the time when the function was run. I have tested

```
os.utime(fileDirectory,
         (st_atime_new, st_mtime_new)
         )
```

on a single file and it works normally to change both st_atime & st_mtime. I'm curious why os.utime() didn't work properly in the loop and whether there's a way to solve the issue. Thanks!

Ps: Windows 10 is my OS and my file system is NTFS

Comment: what operating system are you using? perhaps ext4 with `noatime` set (very common to prevent normally useless writes)?

Comment: @ti7 I'm using Windows 10

Comment: tbh I wouldn't expect much useful POSIX-like capability from NTFS or reasonable time guarantees at all from it [`os.utime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime) and [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) are probably some best-effort